# Make an API that applies all the filters at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to make an API in rails that queries database with a certain filters. The problem is there are around 9-10 columns and i cant go about querying for every combination. I am very new to this, in python/django i used to do it by creating a `dict = {"param": "query_condition"}` and passing it as
`objects = SomeModel.objects.filter(**dict)` . How can i go about this in my rails api when i don't know how many params i will recieve from frontend. Currently my controller looks like this 
`class CharactersController < ApplicationController`

```
def index
    @status  = 200
    @message = ""
    @page    = (params[:page].blank? ? 1 : params[:page].to_i)
    @results = Building.all
    @total   = Building.count
end

def get_residents_with_characters(params)

    @item = Resident.where()`
```

Basically some python like syntax for querying in `get_residents_with_characters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want; I usually go with reducing the model by filters:

```rb
params = {"foo" => "bar", "baz" => "boo"}
query =
  params.reduce(Resident) do |q, (k, v)|
    q.where(k.to_sym => v)
  end
```

Probably some sanitanization etc. is needed upfront.

Comment: so basically my dict would look like `dict = {"column_name" => params[:characters][:column_name]}`

Comment: I have no idea about how your `params` structured, but yes, looks like it.

Comment: ISn't this basically the same as just `Resident.where(params)`?

Comment: @spickermann well, yes and no. The approach above is way more flexible when one wants to somewhat alter the parameters, that is why I showed this approach.

Comment: @speckerman nice! So you can basically pass key val args without reference and ruby will pair column_name and param value for you?